# Django version 3.0.7, TemplateSyntaxError at /cart/ 'cart' is not a registered tag library

Tags: django, templatetags

Error :-

- Request Method:  GET
- Request URL: http://localhost:8000/cart/
- Django Version:  3.0.7
- Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
- Exception Value:
- 'cart' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
- admin_list
- admin_modify
- admin_urls
- cache
- i18n
- l10n
- log
- static
- tz

template tags > cart.py

@register.filter(name='cart_quantity')

```
def cart_quantity(product  , cart):

    keys = cart.keys()
    for id in keys:
        if int(id) == product.id:
             return cart.get(id)
    return 0
```

and the error comes in my .html file which say

- {% load cart %}

I have restart the Django development server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the name given when you register it when you used the decorator

```
{% load cart %}
{{ something | cart_quantity }}
```

Ensure in your app that you have your tags in the proper folder structure

```
-app
    -templatetags
        - cart.py
```

Also, ensure you are calling register correctly

```
from django import template    

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='cart_quantity')
def cart_quantity(product  , cart):
    keys = cart.keys()
    for id in keys:
        if int(id) == product.id:
             return cart.get(id)
    return 0
```

Comment: Didn't worked.It give me" 'cart_quantity' is not a registered tag library. " error message